# CouchDB Response Time Statistic is not being measured

Tags: apache, couchdb

I have a CouchDB instance running on a Windows Server. When I run the command:

`curl http://HOSTNAME:5984/_node/_local/_stats/couchdb/request_time`

I receive the following response:

```
{
  "value": {
    "min": 0.0,
    "max": 0.0,
    "arithmetic_mean": 0.0,
    "geometric_mean": 0.0,
    "harmon ic_mean": 0.0,
    "median": 0.0,
    "variance": 0.0,
    "standard_deviation": 0.0,
    "skewness": 0.0,
    "kurtosis": 0.0,
    "percentile": [
      [
        50,
        0.0
      ],
      [
        75,
        0.0
      ],
      [
        90,
        0.0
      ],
      [
        95,
        0.0
      ],
      [
        99,
        0.0
      ],
      [
        999,
        0.0
      ]
    ],
    "histogram": [
      [
        0,
        0
      ]
    ],
    "n": 0
  },
  "type": "histogram",
  "desc": "length of a request inside CouchDB without MochiWeb"
}
```

I have a few databases on this server and have made roughly 50,000 HTTP requests. Why are all values for the response time metric equal to zero? How can I activate this metric?